# Add Attribute to existing div Tag via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, onclick, attributes

I'm working on a WordPress website.

All I want to do, add the attribute `onclick="off()` to an existing div class via javascript (so that the div always has this attribute when the site is loaded). the content plugin I use creates div's automatically, so instead of editing the source code each time, this seems like a nice and fast solution.

right now I'm trying this, but it doesn't work (i know almost nothing about js):

```
function myfunction() {
    document.getElementById("#content_al").setAttribute("onclick","off")
}
```

I read many threads but didn't get it to work, can anyone help me :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding an event handler you should use `addEventListener`. Below is how you can do it with vanilla javascript.

```
function myfunction() {
    document.getElementById("content_al").addEventListener("click",off)
}
```

where off is  a `function`
 Below is a working snippet. Hope this helps :)

```js
function toggleDisplay() {
  let display = document.getElementById("content_al").style.display;

  document.getElementById("content_al").style.display = display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}

function myfunction() {
  document.getElementById("hide").addEventListener("click", toggleDisplay);
}
myfunction();
```

```html
<div id="content_al"> Some Content </div>

<button id="hide">Hide/Show</button>
```

Comment: didn't work :( maybe something wrong with my code?

<script>
function myfunction() {
    document.getElementById("content_al").addEventListener("click",off)
}
  
function on() {
    document.getElementById("content_al").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("content_al").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

Comment: Please have a look. Have added a working snippet with a few modifications just to demonstrate how it works.

Comment: still didn't work, think i'm doing something wrong. but i want it to be only one button btw. which hides or shows it. can you maybe help me via team viewer or something else?

Comment: @yisharu have updated the code to use one button and have also renamed the function. Its up to you if you want to have two different function or not. I have used just one. If you want to have 2 you will have to call them based on condition

Comment: thank you! i want the content to be a full screen overlay. i got that part working with css. tho now, the button is "not visible" and i would love to have a method to click "anywhere on screen" to close the full screen overlay, you know what i mean? can you maybe help me w/ that pls too :)?

Comment: in that case you can add one event listener to the overlay call the same function and just hide the div i.e set the display property to none. Also i will be able help you better if you can create a demo of what you are trying :)

Comment: works fine, but somehow i have to click the button 2 times to show the div for the first time :/

Comment: I think because the diaplay properry might be coming as null or empty string for the first time. May be you set it to block in css.

Answer (score 2):

- `off` in setAttribute should be `off()`
- Do not pass `#` in `document.getElementById("#content_al")`, instead pass plain id i.e. `content_al`

```js
function myfunction() {
  document.getElementById("content_al").setAttribute("onclick", "off()")
}

function off() {
  console.log("clicked on off!");
}

myfunction();
```

```html
<div id="content_al"> Some Content </div>
```

Comment: it didn't work for me :( maybe there's something in general wrong with my code? <script> function myfunction() { document.getElementById("content_al").addEventListener("click",off) } function on() { document.getElementById("content_al").style.display = "block"; } function off() { document.getElementById("content_al").style.display = "none"; } </script>

Answer (score 1):

try jquery. it's easy

```
jQuery("#content_al").click(function(){
    //do action
});
```

this code defines a click event for your element and you can write your action to run after event fired.